# Magento 2: Set category image programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category

How to set category image programmatically, which shows on list page? I found several solutions on the web but could not solve my problem. I am confused among these functions setThumbnail(), setImage(), setCategoryImage(). I tried all the functions but none of them solved my problem. I will be very thankful if anybody could provide me a code snippet to set category image (and directory where to place that image).

I uploaded the screenshot of adminpanel so that you guys can understand where i want to upload that image.

[image]

My code:

```
try{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory::class);
    $collection = $category->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('name','networking equipment memory')->setPageSize(1);

    if ($collection->getSize()) {
        $categoryobj = $collection->getFirstItem();
        $mediaAttribute = array ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');
        $categoryobj->setImage('/test.jpg', $mediaAttribute, true, false)->save();
    }
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the code below:

```
try{
    $category = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory::class);
    $collection = $category->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('name','Men')->setPageSize(1);
    if ($collection->getSize()) {
        $categoryId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
        $categoryobj = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
        $mediaAttribute = array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');
        $categoryobj->setImage('123456.png', $mediaAttribute, true, false); // make sure image will be in pub/media/catalog/category/
        $categoryobj->setStoreId(0); //admin store id
        $categoryobj->save();
    }
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
```

> Tested Code

Comment: it is not working.

Comment: can you paste your code here?

Comment: edited in my question.

Comment: Hello @umairayub I have make some changes according to your code. I have edit my answer please check now.

Comment: working fine + , set also  $categoryobj->setFeaturedImage('123456.png', $mediaAttribute, true, false);